# How do I convert a column of numerical data into strings in R?

Tags: r

This is my first Stackoverflow post. I'm terrible at R so please bear with me.

I have a dataframe called votedata and a column called district. They are labeled 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5.

I want to regress lm(votepercent ~ votebuypercent + district)

So basically, I need to regress votepercent on votebuypercent, with districts as dummy variables. I tried converting districts into string data, but then I have distinct strings which cause multicolliniarity. What can I do?

Comment: as.character(unique(votedata$district)) if only one instance (of a group) and string desired. But it is likely that, through time, a pot of money was split across districts, and you'd want to aggregate those as well for the regression to make sense, basically suppressing the time nature of the spending.

Comment: You want `lm(votepercent ~ votebuypercent + as.factor(district), votedata)`.